# Why am I getting a NullReferenceException with listbox.SelectedIndex

Tags: vb.net

I run this little piece of code to do a kind of activity log window.

```
Sub writetolog(i As String)
    Try
        'outfile.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy - H:mm:ss:fffffff") & "--->" & i & vbCrLf)
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff") & " - " & i)
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i) = False Then LogLB.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("[" & "MM/dd/yy - HH:mm:ss:ff") & "] -- " & i) 'Else MsgBox(i & " is nothing!")
        If LogLB.Items.Count >= 100 Then LogLB.Items.RemoveAt(0)
        If LogLB.Items.Count > 0 Then LogLB.SelectedIndex = LogLB.Items.Count - 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

So it works most of the time, but for some reason at seemingly random times I get a Null Exception and it points to the end of the line at

```
LogLB.Items.Count - 1
```

Why?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the beginning of the method, and see what is null and why.

Comment: I agree with @ataravati, but also, please post the full stack trace. It doesn't seem possible to get a NullReferenceException in this case.

Comment: Guessing, but if the combo box has no items, is it possible Items or selectedIndex returns null?

Comment: It's hard for me to put a breakpoint in to see when it's happening, because this will run several hundred times with no problem (a few hours worth). If  I put a break point in, I have to know when it's gonna happen, in which case, I'd have to already know why.

Comment: I'll have to learn how to do a stack trace. As a lot of this is still new to me.